# webpack import all code instead of some functions

Tags: javascript, webpack, ramda.js

I have very simple webpack config like this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    test: "./index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

In my file index.js I'm writing some code using Ramda and I'm importing it like this:

```
import { compose, head, tail } from 'ramda';
```

Later I'm making build using `webpack -p`. With few lines of code my build is 59,2Kb and when I'm using `webpack-bundle-analyzer` I see all functions are in the bundle - entire Ramda library. If I'm importing with

```
import ramda from 'ramda';
```

I have the same bundle size. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? I'm using latest webpack version 3.5.5. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ramda doesn't natively use ES2015 modules yet](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1968), and therefore Webpack cannot perform tree shaking on it.

In the meantime, you can import individual modules like so:

```
import compose from "ramda/src/compose";
import head from "ramda/src/head";
import tail from "ramda/src/tail";
```

Alternatively, you can use [babel-plugin-ramda](https://github.com/megawac/babel-plugin-ramda), which analyses your code to figure out which Ramda functions you're actually using and removes the rest.